# AWS Amplify environment variables for pull requests?

Tags: amazon-web-services, environment-variables, aws-amplify

Good evening,

I am new with AWS Amplify.

We have a setup - I didn't set it up - where pull requests to our private Github repository trigger a 'preview' in AWS Amplify.

My understanding is that every preview gets its own preview URL, which is provided by AWS.

Now we have an app where I need to configure a redirect URI. Since the URL cannot be hard-coded I would like to inject it as environment variable at build time.

How can I get access to the URL value?

Only docs I found were these: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/environment-variables.html#amplify-console-environment-variables.

EDIT: Opened a question on Github as well: https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-console/issues/1310.

Answer (score 7):

You can use `AWS_PULL_REQUEST_ID`.

This way, you can get the URL for the PR environment like:

```
https://pr-${AWS_PULL_REQUEST_ID}.${AWS_APP_ID}.amplifyapp.com
```

Comment: One of most useful answers in the world, I have no idea how did you found out about AWS_PULL_REQUEST_ID but thank you!

Comment: Awesome, thanks! How did you find out this? When you google "AWS_PULL_REQUEST_ID aws" you only find this post.

Comment: I just added a line with the command `printenv` into my `amplify.yml` file, and that did the trick!